# Missing default Ubuntu desktop environment in the login screen

Tags: desktop-environments

After installing GNOME desktop environment in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I'm missing Ubuntu default desktop environment...

How can I add it back to the list in the login screen where I can select different desktop environment?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible case, you are using `gdm` after Gnome install. Try switch back to `lightdm` using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Answer (score 0):

This may help: 
Install the ccsm (compiz configure manager), run it, and check the check-box that activates the unity plugin.